# Excel VBA and Document Object Model (DOM) - Error with "variable not defined"

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, excel, dom

My first post on Stack Overflow - thanks for all the posts people have put up here over the years they have helped me to resolve a lot of issues...

Down to the issue at hand though - I am currently creating an excel workbook which skims product information off a number of websites using IE and the document object model approach. I did look to use other methods but some of these sites block crawlers and the information is being pulled off specific sites into a workbook to be analysed so using VBA and DOM seems logical.

On one of the lines I have declared the element and am sourcing the information required via a class name - with a div class as per below:

```
elem.Children(1).getElementsByClassName("pricingSummary")(div).innerText
```

Generally this sources what I need - looking at the element class name for "pricingSummary" on div tags. The issue I have is that intermittently (usually on new workbook open) I will get  vba error of "Variable not defined" with the error referencing the 'div' element of this line.

I can usually get it to go away by adding 3 quotation marks before and after the div tag - and then removing them.

Does anyone have an idea as to what is causing this bizarre behaviour and / or possible alternatives?

Thanks 
C2

Comment: The way you are using `div` is as the ordinal index of a collection the same way you are using `(1)` with `elem.Children(1)` yet you refer to it as a `<div>` tag. In this context, `div` should be variable of type long or integer representing a zero-based index number of the elements having a class of *pricingSummary*. Could you clarify?

Comment: Thanks - I believe you are right.

The material I was using on DOM wasn't for VBA so not sure if this is a VB issue. I'm not familiar with the Document Object Method - just picked it up this last week - but the below resolved my issue:

    elem.Children(1).getElementsByClassName("pricingSummary")(0).innerText